# I need to join table and matching parameters

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables A and B as follows and i need to join or match the parameter such as if the mjclass='PKG' then check the risktype from table A and and go to table B and assign the value associate with risk_type variable in the new column say New_CTR. Please share the SQl query.

Please help me out, Thanks in advance.

**Table A**

```
id name  mjclass risktype
-------------------------
1  tanu  ACC     RGD
2  Jeet  PKG     RGE
3  Sunil PKG     RGG
5  hema  PIB     TMC
6  jeet  Eng     ACC
7  preet PKG     RGE
8  Rakul PKG     TGF
```

**Table B**

```
risk_type  Major_Class
-----------------------
 RGD       ACC
 RGE       TMC
 TMC       TCG
 TGF       TTM
 ACC       TTC
```

Comment: Please also add the expected output here if possible.

Comment: Did you try using Access query builder and joining tables on risk type fields?

Comment: please Provide  expected output.?

Answer (score 0):

This smells like a JOIN.

```
SELECT 
  a.id, a.name, a.mjclass, b.risk_type
FROM TableA AS a
LEFT JOIN TableB AS b
ON a.mjclass=b.Major_Class
WHERE a.mjclass='PKG'
```

*Definitely worth reading up more about them as this will make SQL so much more enjoyable*

Comment: Thank you for your response, yesterday only i have achieved this. But I have one doubt If i created new example [mjcla]& CTR as CTR_1 so can i use this CTR_1 in same query. and how i can use it please help me.